# Socket Crashes Thread

Tags: java, sockets, runnable

**Problem:**

My `@Override run()` method which is part of the class that implements Runnable, is called constantly like normal. However, the moment I open up a socket connection, that thread seems to stop, without throwing any errors. If I connect the client to a server socket, it works just fine, however the GUI which is being ticked by the `@Override run()` method just stops working

Run Method:

```
@Override
public void run()
{

}
```

Server Socket (which stops the run() method from being invoked):

```
public class CommonProxy
{

    public static boolean isActive = false;

    public static void startServer() throws IOException
    {
        isActive = true;

        Socket socket;

        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        ServerSocket serverSocket;

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);

        while (isActive)
        {
            try
            {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("hi");

                outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                while (isActive)
                {
                    String clientMessage = bufferedReader.readLine();

                    System.out.println("[Client]: " + clientMessage);

                    bufferedWriter.write("Message Recieved");
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.flush();

                    if (clientMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Client Disconnected");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                socket.close();
                inputStreamReader.close();
                outputStreamWriter.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Client socket (which also stops the method from being invokes) if needed:

```
    public static void startClient(String address, int port)
    {
        isActive = true;

        Socket socket = null;

        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try
        {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.0.100", 1234);
            System.out.println(socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());

            outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            while (isActive)
            {
                String queuedMessage = scanner.nextLine();

                bufferedWriter.write(queuedMessage);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.flush();

                System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());

                if (queuedMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (socket != null) socket.close();
                if (inputStreamReader != null) inputStreamReader.close();
                if (outputStreamWriter != null) outputStreamWriter.close();
                if (bufferedReader != null) bufferedReader.close();
                if (bufferedWriter != null) bufferedWriter.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void queueMessage(String message)
    {
        queuedMessage = message;
    }

    public static String getMessage()
    {
        return lastServerMessage;
    }
```

Comment: You should run them in separate threads,  calling `serverSocket.accept()` or `new Socket("192.168.0.100", 1234)` will block your thread. also reading information will block the thread.

Comment: Sorry, I've only ever used one thread... is this what is called multithreading? Also, what would that look like? would I simply make another thread object? if so, where would I make it? In the main class which implements runnable, or in the server class? and what would the other thread do? I'm not entirely sure how that would work, sorry. I just don't have enough experience with this particular field. (This is my first multiplayer game)

Comment: Yes, this is multithreading. If you have runnable called `run`, you can start new thread: `new Thread(run).start()`. be careful when you access the same variable from multiple thread,  this can cause issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I'm making a game, so I will have to access a variable from the socket thread, by the game thread. Will this cause an issue? If so, how can I avoid it? Is using getters and setters a solution?

Comment: accessing variables wont cause issues, but modifying them can, for example, if you try to add items to list with one thread and read them with other. to solve this issue, you can use synchronization (https://www.google.com/search?q=synchronization+java&oq=synchronization+java&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j0i22i30l8.9698j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) if you still don't understand feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you! This will work! Just one question: the document about Synchronization is if I'm modifying variables right? From the sounds of it, I will get a synchronization issue if I have 3 different threads running and thread 1 has a variable, thread 2 changes that variable, and thread 3 access that variable correct? Because if that's the case, I think I will only ever have 2 threads running: the game, and the client or the host

Comment: oops, i meant to give you this link https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized. and no two threads are enough to cause issues, i will write a code to show you in a moment

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RO54GdZ8JCAjv0Bf4BUz2pjdGM_FZYdm?usp=sharing

Comment: Tell me when you done reading and understanding the files or when you downloaded them, so I will delete them